# Fields and Euclidean Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

While proving that every Field is a Euclidean ring, how can one show that Euclidean Function v(x)=1 satisfies the Euclidean postulate.

Comment: I don't recognize your notation.  Are you defining the Euclidean function of an indeterminate element of your field to be one (and thereby asserting that $x$ is a unit) or ...  what?

Answer (score 2):

Let me make sure we are on the same page in regards to definitions.

$F$ is a field and you want to define a function $f$ from $F\setminus \{0\}$ to the non-negative integers such that "If $a,b\in F$ and $b$ is nonzero, then there are $q$ and $r$ in $F$ such that $a = bq + r$ and either $r = 0$ or $f(r) < f(b)$".

Since in a field you have multiplicative inverses for all elements, take $q=b^{-1}a$ and $r=0$. You don't need to worry about $f$ at all, just that it maps to non-negative integers. So, your example $f(x)=1$ will work.

Note: Some authors require a little more, e.g. that "for all nonzero a and b in $F$, $f(a) ≤ f(ab)$". See the discussion on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain). Keep in mind that in a field, every non-zero element is a unit.

${}{}{}$